# Problem while disabling scrolling of UITableview

Tags: iphone

I am facing a problem while disabling the scrolling of table view.When i disabled the scrolling then the cells are not responding to user clicks,even delegates( like - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath) are not firing .Still dont know how to resolve looking for a solution
Thanks in advance....

Comment: I have UITableView with disabled scrolling and it works ok for me... May be you just accidently turned off "User interaction enabled" property?.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the property `scrollEnabled` inside your UITableViewController code. I tested the following successfully:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work by using
In objC,

```
[_tblRoadBooks setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

In swift,

```
tbl.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Hope it will help you :)